# How can I achieve greater City/Civilization Upgrade details?

Tags: homebrew, character-advancement, dawn-of-worlds

When playing Dawn of Worlds, we usually spend a lot of time coming up with neat things for cities and civilizations to develop.  Unfortunately, the only thing such upgrades are used for in the base system is warfare.  What mechanics can I best use to better integrate these upgrades into gameplay?  I prefer clear, internally consistent mechanics when adding subsystems, and I want any resource expenditures in the added subsystem(s) to be balanced with the resource expenditures in the base game.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such systems included in the game, however I have personally divided technology into nine trees:

- Warfare
- Food
- Spirit
- Lumber
- Mining
- Magic
- Medicine
- Trade
- Architecture

Each of these work as an 1.5<sup>Tech level</sup> as multiplier. After each round a city gathers 1×population modifier×1.5<sup>related technology</sup>/1.5<sup>corruption</sup> resources. Then they use those resources in order to increase the population modifier for resources×1.5<sup>architecture</sup>×1.5<sup>medicine</sup>/1.5<sup>population</sup> modifier.

It worked well, though there was a lot of bookkeeping by the end game. It added about 10 minutes per round, so you might want to avoid it if you don't feel like taking that long.

Comment: Homebrew on this site is expected to be backed with personal experience; you should probably actually try using this and _then_ making an answer.

Comment: If you do test it, though, please do report back with your experiences and what worked and what didn't!  I'm very much willing to bounty a good answer to this question.

Comment: I tested it and it worked well through there was a lot of book keeping by the end game so you might want to avoid it if you don't feel like taking 10 minutes per round.

Comment: I've added the critical experience-based information. I've also attempted to format the math more clearly. You may want to look over the changes & make sure there are no errors.